# C++ arrays as pointers question

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

Why this is possible:

```
char buf[10], *pbuf = buf, **ppbuf = &pbuf;
```

and this isn't:

```
char buf[10], **ppbuf = &buf;
```

As I understand, the second line is just a shorthand of the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&buf` has the wrong type. `&buf` is a pointer to an array of 10 `char`. `ppbuf` has to be initialized with a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

In the first initialization, while `buf` denotes an array, it decays to a `char*` pointing to its first element so the initialization is valid.

You also can't do: `char buf[10], **ppbuf = &(&buf[0]);` because `&buf[0]` is not an lvalue so you can't take its address.

Comment: The name of an array isn't the address of it's firest element? Or Does it work only in function's arguments?

Comment: @dimayak: The array variable converts implicitly to the address of its first element (a char*), when appropriate. But it is not a pointer to a char*.

Comment: @dimayak: No. The name of an array is the name of an array. It decays to a pointer to its first element in expression contexts other than as an argument to unary `&` or `sizeof`.

Answer (score 5):

They're not equivalent.

```
*pbuf = buf
```

That means, "`pbuf` is a pointer to type `char`, whose value is the address of `buf`." Since `buf` is an array of chars, this works.

```
**ppbuf = &pbuf
```

That means, "`ppbuf` is a pointer to a pointer to type `char`, whose value is the address of `pbuf`." Since `pbuf` is a pointer to type `char`, this works.

```
**ppbuf = &buf
```

This means, "`ppbuf` is a pointer to a pointer to type `char`, whose value is the address of `buf`." Since `buf` is an array of chars, this fails.

Answer (score 2):

buf is an array, not a pointer, so you can't assign its address to a pointer pointer. `pbuf` *is* a pointer (to the first element of the array), so you *can* assign its address to a pointer pointer.

Think of the code this way:

```
typedef char* char_p;

char buf[10];
char_p *ppbuf = &buf;  // If this was legal...
*ppbuf = NULL;         // what would this mean?
```

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to see it's not the same when you start from:

```
*pbuf = buf
```

Since the indirection of pbuf is buf, pbuf contains the address of buf, thus:

```
pbuf = &buf
```

So:

```
**ppbuf != pbuf
**ppbuf != &buf
```